# Check whether zoom level changed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, mapkit, mkmapview

I'm using MapKit on iPhone.
How can I know when the user changes the zoom level (zoom in\out the map)?

I've tried to use **mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated;** but that's called even when the map is only dragged.
Unfortunately, when the map is dragged the mapView.region.span changes as well...

Help?

10x

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It is pretty simple to calculate the zoom level. See the snippet below. You can get the mRect parameter from the `visibleMapRect` property on your `MKMapView` instance.

```
+ (NSUInteger)zoomLevelForMapRect:(MKMapRect)mRect withMapViewSizeInPixels:(CGSize)viewSizeInPixels
{
    NSUInteger zoomLevel = MAXIMUM_ZOOM; // MAXIMUM_ZOOM is 20 with MapKit
    MKZoomScale zoomScale = mRect.size.width / viewSizeInPixels.width; //MKZoomScale is just a CGFloat typedef
    double zoomExponent = log2(zoomScale);
    zoomLevel = (NSUInteger)(MAXIMUM_ZOOM - ceil(zoomExponent));
    return zoomLevel;
}
```

You could probably just stop at the step for calculating the `zoomScale` as that will tell you if the zoom has changed at all.

I figured this stuff out from reading Troy Brants excellent blog posts on the topic:

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/mkmapview-and-zoom-levels-a-visual-guide/

**Swift 3**

```
extension MKMapView {

    var zoomLevel: Int {
        let maxZoom: Double = 20
        let zoomScale = self.visibleMapRect.size.width / Double(self.frame.size.width)
        let zoomExponent = log2(zoomScale)
        return Int(maxZoom - ceil(zoomExponent))
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow! this looks like exactly what I need.
To sharpen things a bit - Where do I get viewSizeInPixels from?

Comment: viewSizeInPixels is the bounds.size property of your MKMapView instance

Comment: Quite helpful, needed to determine if the map is zoomed in to the max. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, please can you tell me how should i call this method you post please, it requires parameters, what value should i put when i call it, thx in advance ;)

Comment: In case it isn't immediately obvious you can get the `mapRect` from `visibleMapRect` property of the MKMapView instance.

Comment: I have tried to use your code but found some strange thing. I have made some debugging and I'm confused now. `MKZoomScale zoomScale` returns me something like 4727 but when I get zoom in `- (BOOL)canDrawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale` it is about 0.000488.... Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 11):

I found this very helpful and developed the following code based on these answers.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated 
{
   mapRegion = self.mapView.region;
}


-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated{

MKCoordinateRegion newRegion = self.mapView.region;

NSInteger zFactor;
if ((mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta/newRegion.span.latitudeDelta) > 1.5){
    NSLog(@"Zoom in changed");
    zFactor = 20;
    CustomPlacemark *aO; 
    MKAnnotationView *aV; 
    for (aO in self.mapView.annotations) {
        aV = [[self mapView] viewForAnnotation:aO];
        aV.frame = CGRectMake(aV.frame.origin.x, aV.frame.origin.y, aV.frame.size.width+zFactor, aV.frame.size.height+zFactor);
        [[[self mapView] viewForAnnotation:aO] setFrame:aV.frame];
    }
}
if ((mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta/newRegion.span.latitudeDelta) < 0.75){
    NSLog(@"Zoom out");
    zFactor = -20;
    CustomPlacemark *aO; 
    MKAnnotationView *aV; 
    for (aO in self.mapView.annotations) {
        aV = [[self mapView] viewForAnnotation:aO];
        aV.frame = CGRectMake(aV.frame.origin.x, aV.frame.origin.y, aV.frame.size.width+zFactor, aV.frame.size.height+zFactor);
        [[[self mapView] viewForAnnotation:aO] setFrame:aV.frame];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My initial attempt was 90% of this solution, the span ratio is what I was missing (I was expecting a simple move to keep the same lat/lon span range, I was incorrect)

Answer (score 4):

*Much more simpler answer:*

The easiest way to get an Integer of the current zoom level, is by using the MapView function: regionDidChangeAnimated. This function recognizes every change in zoom and will give you the basis for the calculation of the zoom factor.

Just insert this function into your MapView class (**works for Swift 3.0**):

```
var mapView: MKMapView! = nil

...

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    let zoomWidth = mapView.visibleMapRect.size.width
    let zoomFactor = Int(log2(zoomWidth)) - 9
    print("...REGION DID CHANGE: ZOOM FACTOR \(zoomFactor)")
}
```

And you will get a zoomFactor value out of it, where 0 is the most near point you can zoom into the map and every higher value is a far far away zoom... :-)

Comment: Yup this is called whenever the map actually changes which is when I car about the zoom. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have the following MKMapView category in which I include a method for quickly getting the current zoom level for the map:

```
@implementation MKMapView (ZoomLevel)

- (NSUInteger) zoomLevel {
    MKCoordinateRegion region = self.region;

    double centerPixelX = [MKMapView longitudeToPixelSpaceX: region.center.longitude];
    double topLeftPixelX = [MKMapView longitudeToPixelSpaceX: region.center.longitude - region.span.longitudeDelta / 2];

    double scaledMapWidth = (centerPixelX - topLeftPixelX) * 2;
    CGSize mapSizeInPixels = self.bounds.size;
    double zoomScale = scaledMapWidth / mapSizeInPixels.width;
    double zoomExponent = log(zoomScale) / log(2);
    double zoomLevel = 21 - zoomExponent;

    return zoomLevel;
}

@end
```

To obtain the zoom level, you can call the following in your delegates and determine if the zoom level has changed:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSUInteger zoomLevel = [mapView zoomLevel];
}
```

Comment: This is wonderful except -longitudeToPixelSpaceX: is a big unknown.

Comment: MKMapRect visibleRect = self.visibleMapRect;
 double centerPixelX = visibleRect.origin.x+visibleRect.size.width/2;
 double topLeftPixelX = visibleRect.origin.x;

Comment: I have recently simplified this in my own apps, which works well and is more concise https://gist.github.com/4178336

Answer (score 1):

you can listen to the `mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:` method. However, this doesn't tell you if the zoom level changed, just if the map was animated.

You will also need to listen to the `region` property of the map view. This contains the latitudeDelta and the longitudeDelta values which can be used to calculate if the zoom level has changed.

i.e. in the .h file

```
@class MyMapViewController {
    ...
    MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;
    }
@end
```

and in your .m file

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    mapRegion = mapView.region;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    newRegion = mapView.region;

    if (mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta != newRegion.span.latitudeDelta ||
        mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta != newRegion.span.longitudeDelta)
        NSLog(@"The zoom has changed");
}
```

This should detect if the map zoom has changed.

however, you should wach out for the zoom changing because the earth is curved :( If the map is scrolled the latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta will change slightly just because of the shape of the Earth, not because the user has zoomed. You might have to detect a large change in the deltas and ignore slight changes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Much more complete answer than mine. I think the longitude delta changes as you go towards the poles, but the latitude delta stays constant wherever you go. Might need some testing to check that it's constant enough to use.

Comment: I can never remember which changes and which doesn't so I've just tested both in my answer :) I suppose you could test to see if they bost change it must be a user zoom, if only one changes it much be a scroll?

Comment: Guys I wish you could just had a slight check to your "solutions" before publishing them. 
Non of your ideas work. The span delta does change - and change a lot.

Comment: 5 minutes testing tells me that latitudeDelta changes all the time, longitudeDelta changes only when you zoom so my answer will work if you only test the longitudeDelta. And we're not here to solve it for you, we're here to help you find the solution yourself, which I think we did.

Comment: no problem and tbh, I should have put in my answer that it was untested :)

Answer (score 0):

**Count zoom scale in MKMapView - Swift solution**

I created following extension for MKMapView, so you can get a scale of zoom on map. The solution is similar as presented above but in Swift.

There is also additional function `scaleWithPrecision(_:Int64)` for rounding that scale what allow to filter out f.ex. little zoom changes on MapView

```
extension MKMapView {

    var scale: Double {

        return self.scaleWithPrecision(1)
    }

    func scaleWithPrecision(precision: Int64) -> Double {

        let mapBoundsWidth = Double(self.bounds.size.width)
        let mapRectWidth:Double = self.visibleMapRect.size.width

        let scale: Double = round(Double(precision)*mapBoundsWidth/mapRectWidth)/Double(precision)

        return scale
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could save a latitude delta, then when `regionDidChangeAnimated:` is called, check to see if the new latitude delta is different. I think the latitude delta stays constant as long as the map isn't zoomed.

Comment: well, you're wrong.
the span values do change as you drag the map.