# MKMapView: any way to tell max/min visibleRect (zoom level)?

Tags: mkmapview

Is there a constant or method for determining the maximum and minimum zoom level or visible rect of MKMapView?  I'm looking even for a proxy solution such as getting a "visibleRectForRect:" method perhaps.  The goal is to know when a map is "fully zoomed in" (etc) and change the display settings of related UI accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you can calculate the zoomLevel (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359424/check-whether-zoom-level-changed), we can reasonably-safely assume that the zoom level is bracketed between 1 and 21 (not future-proofed but certainly constant for some years now).

Thus, check the zoom level and use whatever threshold is "max" for your app.  In my tests I could never get the map to go beyond 3-19, so I use that.