# Is possible, in MapKit, disable only zoom in?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

Inside:

```
mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool)
```

I calculate a level zoom. If this zoom level satisfy a condition I would like disable **only** zoom in and zoom out remains enabled.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible disable only zoom-in with MapKit. My solution is: check zoomLevel, if it is greater than a prefixed level reposition map to a fixed zoomLevel.

Answer (score 0):

You could set [`isZoomEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452577-iszoomenabled) to `false`:

> This property controls only user interactions with the map. If you set
>   the value of this property to false, you may still change the zoom
>   level programmatically by changing the value in the region property.

According to your need, you could

```
mapView.isZoomEnabled = false
```

when it's needed. For instance, you might check the zooming level if it's aiming to increase and disable it.

In addition, [Check whether zoom level changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359424/check-whether-zoom-level-changed) might be useful to your case.

Comment: But when I set isZoomEnabled to false the zoom level will not change anymore because the map zoom is disable. So I can't reset attribute isZoomEnabled to true